# Is it possible to execute a function on all members of an array all at once?

Tags: php, arrays, function, asynchronous, foreach

Context :

```
$a = array('1','2','3');
foreach ($a as $item){
  //rest of code
  //example file_get_contents(url);
  //the script waits for it to be completed before going to the next
}
```

The above script goes one by one.

My concern is, when a process on a single element takes *too long*, the remaining elements have to wait to be processed.

Is it possible to do *stuff* to all array items all at once?

Comment: I may not understand you correctly but your question does not make too much sense to me. 1. Unlike nodejs, it does not work in parallel in PHP in my understanding 2. Whether you can execute the whole array depends on the function you called 3. Even if the downstream function accept an array as parameter, it will have a foreach loop as long as items in your array needed to be dealt with separately, and result in same performance... if I did not answer your question maybe you should elaborate more on what your problem is

Comment: This question is at risk of being closed because of a lack of clarity.  I have edited your question to try to improve it, but if my edit misrepresents your question, please re-edit or rollback the question.

Comment: @JohnR if you can tell us what _stuff_ you want to do to your array, we can help you find the best array manipulating function, but all of your php processes will work in sequence.

Comment: Inside the "forearch //rest of code" I do a file_get_contents(url)... the problem is that some site take more time than other and it "hangs" the srcipt. I'm looking for do stuff in parrallel... (i guess)

Comment: PHP doesn't provide multi-threading or asynchronous execution. They can be achieved in several ways (using extensions, forking the script or launching external processes) but they are cumbersome. Most of the times the goal isn't worth the effort. What exactly is the *stuff* you want to do in parallel?

Comment: array_walk have the same "hang" issue

Comment: example : rss feed, I want to check for new feed items for a bunch of sites. the problem is that some sites take way much time to respond... check 2 sites is ok, but when it come to 30, 100, etc it takes for ever to process... I'm looking for execution in parrallel

Comment: @JohnR To stand the best change of receiving a quality answer without a terribly long wait, please take a moment to edit your question and describe to the best of your ability all of the functions and data that you are working with.  Shows us what your have researched and what your've tried.  Give us a few sample rss feeds to play with.  Tell us exactly what needs to be achieved.  Only after doing this will you get the best possible advice and answers.  I also recommend pinging axiac when you are done (s)he is no fool.

Comment: In doing some digging, I stumbled upon "curl_multi_init" ... (multiple cURL handles asynchronously) -->> I'll do some test and get back with an answer

Comment: I found "rooling curl" on github... https://github.com/joshfraser/rolling-curl ... doing further testing and will answer a working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some search I found Rolling curl
https://github.com/joshfraser/rolling-curl

I took the included example.php I make it a bit shorter

```
require("RollingCurl.php");
$urls = array(); // regular array, or from csv or from Database...

function request_callback($response, $info) {
    // parse the page title out of the returned HTML
    if (preg_match("~<title>(.*?)</title>~i", $response, $out)) {
        $title = $out[1];
    }
    echo "<b>$title</b>";
    print_r($info);
    echo "<hr>";
}

$rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");
$rc->window_size = 20;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $request = new RollingCurlRequest($url);
    $rc->add($request);
}
$rc->execute();
```